# Stack usage (-Wstack-usage) incorrectly calculated in switch cases when returning a variant (C++, GCC)

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, stack, variant

```
struct TestStruct
{
    std::array<char, 100> bigBoi{};
};

std::variant<TestStruct> GetVariant()
{
    return TestStruct{};
    return TestStruct{};
}
```

The function GetVariant() is flagged by -Wstack-usage for more than twice the size of the array in TestStruct when optimization is disabled (-O0). -O1 fixes the problem.

Here it is in godbolt:

https://godbolt.org/z/rPnxKqdaq

More obvious use case (where this was found):

```
std::variant<TestStruct> GetVariant(ENUM enum)
{
    switch (enum)
    {
        case CASE1:
            return TestStruct{};
        case CASE2:
            return TestStruct{};
    }
}
```

Anyone know anything about this? Compiler bug?

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:
This compiles just fine, the problem is definitely related to variant:

```
TestStruct GetStruct()
{
    return TestStruct{};
    return TestStruct{};
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hnTd1Kzsd

Comment: What makes you think that this is a compiler bug?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik -Wstack-usage is adding every possible (and impossible) branch's stack consumption together. Even two returns (as shown in the post) are added together as the total stack consumption of this function.

Comment: There's nothing in the nearly two thousand pages that comprises the current C++ standard that governs this aspect of a compiler's behavior. The compiler is instructed to turn off all optimization. The compiler turns off all optimizations and literally compiles the code, as is, allocating automatic storage for every object that gets instantiated in automatic scope.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "allocating automatic storage for every object that gets instantiated in automatic scope" seems far too inefficient for even O0, is that the case? Have I vastly underestimated how bad O0 is?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This compiles just fine:

TestStruct GetStruct()
{
    return TestStruct{};
    return TestStruct{};
}

https://godbolt.org/z/hnTd1Kzsd

It's definitely related to variant.

Comment: Maybe it's too inefficient, I would agree. But being inefficient is not a compiler bug.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik With my last edit and comment I've found that "allocating automatic storage for every object that gets instantiated in automatic scope" is not followed when the return isn't a variant. Why the discrepancy? This discrepancy is what leads me to believe it's more of a bug than a quirk.

Comment: It would be accurate to call something a bug when it's shown to violate some part of the C++ standard, and produces an incorrect result. This is out of scope of the C++ standard. There's nothing in the C++ standard that prohibits a compiler from allocating automatic storage for every object in automatic scope, in a function, even when their scopes are independent of each other.

Comment: Great question overall, but please don't start your question off with a code snippet. Instead, explain your predicament, your problem, and things you have tried. Only after that you should post your code snippet.